# Is it possible for a query to have none existent group value but returns null for its row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a poll, first this is my tables

PollTable

```
[pid][title][choices]
```

Choices are dynamic, at least 2 choices are needed, it is constructed with delimiter

Example:

```
'Apple|Grape|Banana'
```

another table is the Response table where I store the user response

```
[pid][uid][answer]
```

Example data:

```
1-1-1 //where pid - uid - answer
1-2-1
1-3-2
1-4-3
1-5-3
```

Using this query I can get the number of response per answer

```
SELECT `answer`, COUNT(`answer`) as 'response' 
FROM `poll_response` WHERE `pid` = 1 GROUP BY `answer`
```

Result

```
[ answer ][ response ]
[    1   ][     2    ]
[    2   ][     1    ]
[    3   ][     2    ]
```

that worked fine except when there are no respondent for a certain choice

Example:

```
1-1-1
1-2-1
1-3-1
1-4-3
1-5-3
```

this would give me

```
[ answer ][ response ]
[    1   ][     3    ]
[    3   ][     2    ]
```

but what I needed is

```
[ answer ][ response ]
[    1   ][     3    ]
[    2   ][     0 or null    ]
[    3   ][     2    ]
```

I know this can be done with LEFT JOIN to the POLL table if each of the choices has their own column, but then again the choices is dynamic, it can be more than 10 or any X.

is it possible with the current setup? any ideas?

Comment: how to mysql can know answer = 2 exists? or 4? I think this is not possible without additional table with answers codes.

Comment: I fear thats impossible as well :( thanks for your insight bummi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two interesting issues in your question. One is how to determine the number of choices, and the other is how to generate a sequence of numbers without creating a table which you can use to find the "missing" answers.

On the first, some string manipulation can help you. If the delimiter is always "|" then the expression `length(choices)-length(replace(choices,"|",""))+1` gives you the number of choices for the poll.

On the second issue, there is probably a way using inline variables (@row, etc.) to generate the sequence, but a simpler way in the case where you have a finite maximum set of choices might be a simple union, along the lines of `select 1 as counter union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5` for example.

Combine the above to find the items in the sequence that received no answer with a `not exists` from the response table. Use the string expression to limit items from the sequence to those less than the maximum number of choices available for the given poll. For example:

```
select counter as answer, 0 as response
from polltable p,
  (select 1 as counter union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) as options
where p.pid=1
  and not exists (
    select answer from response r
    where r.pid=1
      and answer=counter)
  and counter<=length(choices)-length(replace(choices,"|",""))+1
```

Finally, union your initial query that has the answered choices with the above. Here's a sample [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d122d/5).

Comment: that string expression made it possible! I will try it with different scenarios, Thanks wwkudu. I got the feeling this might do it

Answer (score 0):

I think its impossible..

but what do you think of this approach using javascript? is it reasonable?

the data are pass in json so

i did this

```
choices = data[0]['choices'].split('|'); //Where data is the SELECT * for the Poll Table
```

which now has

```
["Apple" , "Grape", "Banana"]
```

Now I do this to make a container for the responses

```
var response = new Array( choices.length+1 ).join('0').split('').map(parseFloat);
```

which has

```
[ 0, 0, 0 ]
```

and entered in this loop

```
    for( x=0; x<responsedata.length; x++ ){
        response[ parseInt( responsedata[x]['answer']-1 ) ] = parseInt( responsedata[x]['response'] );

        //Where responsedata is the result of
        //SELECT `answer`, COUNT(`answer`) as 'response' 
        //FROM `poll_response` WHERE `pid` = 1 GROUP BY `answer`
    }
```

so now I have this in my response array

```
[3, 0, 2]
```

Comment: Seems also like a practical approach.